# How to pass result from BottomSheetDialogFragment to Activity which started it?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have attached BottomSheetDialogFragment to one of my fragment.In that bottom sheet ,I have given option

1. open gallery
2. open camera

**For Open gallery**

```
private void startGallery() {
        Intent intentGallery = new Intent(baseActivity, SelectImage.class);
        intentGallery.putExtra("LIMIT", 10);
      startActivityForResult(intentGallery, REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);

        return;
    }
```

This code i have written in `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.But the response of 
**onActivityResult()** , i want to listen in Fragment which initiated it at first place. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Make a method `onActivityResult` in BottomSheetDialogFragment with same signature.

```
public class ActivityA {

BottomSheetFragment bottomSheet;

...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        bottomSheet.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

**Edit**

If you want to listen `onActivityResult` in Fragment then call

```
startActivityForResult(intentGallery, SpotCuesUtils.REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);
```

If you want listen in `Activity` then call like

```
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intentGallery, SpotCuesUtils.REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);
```

**Edit2**

After understanding your requirement. I want let you know that this can be implemented in many ways. I tell you one.

Just pass your Fragment instance in BottomSheetFragment when you open it.

Like

```
bottomSheet.setParentFragment(this);
bottomSheet.show(...);
```

Then in your `bottomSheet`.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    parentFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Or you can `startActivityForResult` from fragment instance

```
parentFragment.startActivityForResult(...);
```

Then you will get this response in your parent Fragment.

Comment: onActivityResult of ActivityA . is not getting called

Comment: startActivityForResult(intentGallery, REQUEST_GALLERY_CODE);  using same for fragment.

Comment: And where you want listen?

Comment: From the fragment from where bottom sheet is open.

Comment: @Khemraj I have Fragment that extends from BottomSheetDialogFragment! 
I have Two options like a question , capture from camera or choose from gallery! but do not work. The activityResult do not call! I try a lot but did not work yet

Comment: @sanaebadi first of all, how are you, its been many months seen you. and about question, it should work. I don't know why this is not working your side

Comment: tnx @Khemraj , I solved it! I am okat=y how about u ?!